# How To Make New Field Appear When A Checkbox Is Ticked In Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form

I had created a form with wordpress contact form 7 and here is how the shortcodes looks like :

```
<p>Name</p><br />
[text* your-name] </p>

<p>E-mail<br />
[email* your-email] </p>

<p>Subject<br />
[text your-subject] </p>

<p>Message<br />
[textarea your-message] </p>
<p>Where did you hear about us?<br />
[checkbox* your-country "Google search" "referral" "link" "Advertisement"]</p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

But in the checkbox area when people select Google Search I would like a new field to appear where people can write which keyword they used.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you please share generated html code of your contact form? actually i want your contact form ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this `[text* text-875 "please indicate if Google search keyword)"] right next to [checkbox* your-country "Google search" "referral" "link" "Advertisement"]

so it will look like this

```
<p>Where did you hear about us?<br />
[checkbox* your-country "Google search" "referral" "link" "Advertisement"] [text* text-875 "please indacte if Google search key word)"] </p>
```

or you can do it in radio buttons like this:

```
<p>Where did you hear about us?<br />   
[radio radio-100 class:radio-vertical "referral" "link" "Advertisement" "Google search, please indicate key word"] [text text-388] </p>
```